# Why is Surefire not executing my JUnit5 tests?

Tags: junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to convert one Maven SpringBoot (2.3.12) app from JUnit4 to JUnit5.  I've read many different posts on how to do this.

I'm able to execute my JUnit5 tests in Eclipse.

My problem is that I am unable to get Maven Surefire to execute my JUnit5 tests.  I've tried various configuration variations.  When it gets to the Surefire step, it ONLY executes my old JUnit4 tests and simply ignores any JUnit5 tests.  I've verified that if one of those JUni4 tests is executed from this, and I convert that test to JUnit5, it will then ignore that test.  At this point, I'm only focusing on the tests that were using the Mockito runner, as they are simpler to convert than the Spring runner tests (the vast majority of which likely could be changed to just use the mockito runner).

This is what I have in the surefire plugin config:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>          
            <configuration>
                <!-- <groups>UnitTest</groups> -->
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/component/*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/contract/*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/integration/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.8.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I currently have "groups" commented out until I understand what it is doing without that.

This is an excerpt of one of the unit tests:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BDSHelperTest {
```

Before I converted this to use the JUnit5 classes, it would execute when I run "mvn package". Now that I've converted it, Surefire is not executing it.

This is what I see at the start of the surefire step:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ NotesMs ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
```

At this point, it shows the test runs for all the old JUnit4 tests, but it doesn't run any of the JUnit5 tests.

Comment: one thing to remember is the filenames matter, e.g. must be include "Test". I had trouble running junit4 & 5 tests together, so I went all in and converted them to 5. Only dependency is <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>

Comment: Can you please post a full pom file or even better a "working" example project?

Comment: There will be more information coming, but it's been determined that this is a bug in Surefire, which will be resolved by a PR that @tibor17 submitted.

Comment: New version 3.0.0-M6 was deployed to Maven Central which includes this fix as well. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I am the Apache developer of Surefire. I have created a project which proves that it works with Surefire **3.0.0-M5**, JUnit Jupiter 5.8.2 and Mockito Extension.
Please do not use JUnit4 and Vintage in this case.
It is not necessary to use a dependency inside of the plugin.
Use a dependency in the project POM.
Follow it on Github:
https://github.com/Tibor17/junit5-mockito-examples

Comment: Will this also execute JUnit 4 tests?  Will it execute spring-runner tests?

Comment: Yes, sure!
I have updated the project and the surefire provider executes both JUnit4 and JUnit5 tests. The Surefire is very intelligent because it downloads and uses Vintage and Jupiter engines even if you do not specify them in the project dependencies. It's enough to use API, e.g. org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter which has transitive dep org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api or junit:junit:4.13.2.

Comment: New version 3.0.0-M6 was deployed to Maven Central which includes this fix as well. Enjoy!

Comment: Yup, I noticed the announcement. We're going to queue up a test for it today.

Comment: Just tried M5 and it worked for me!  Thank you!